# Remove a specific camera background image via python

Tags: python, camera

I'm making an addon that allows to easily point to some images and add them as a sequence background image to the scene camera:

```py
cam = bpy.context.scene.camera

bpy.context.scene.camera.data.background_images.clear()

img = bpy.data.images.load(notePath)
img.source = 'SEQUENCE'
img.name = 'SketchNotes'
cam.data.show_background_images = True
bg = cam.data.background_images.new()
bg.image = img
bg.image_user.frame_duration = bpy.context.scene.frame_end
bg.image_user.frame_start = 1
bg.frame_method = 'CROP'
```

Now, since it is intended to be used potentially many times, and each time with new files that make the previous ones outdated, I would like to remove any background image previously made by the addon. And that's where I am stuck.

From this: [CameraBackgroundImages(bpy_struct) — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CameraBackgroundImages.html)

I figure I should use `remove(image)`, but I can't figure out how to use it to target **only** the background images made by my addon. I was hoping I could use the image name `SketchNotes` to target it.
I can't either use indexes as in `bpy.ops.view3d.background_image_remove(index=0)` because I can't be sure the user will use the background images in any particular order (plus this one requires specific contexts to work).

In the meantime I use `bpy.context.scene.camera.data.background_images.clear()` as in my second line, which works, but it can annoy some people that would want to keep other background images that should not be bothered by my script.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `remove` method takes the background image object as argument. So in case of your code snippet:

```
cam.data.background_images.remove(bg)
```

And I think you have to call the `update` method after that to update the UI.

```
cam.data.background_images.update()
```

When you don't have the background image object in memory anymore, but the image name instead, you can always search for it, of course:

```
for bgi in cam.data.background_images:
    if bgi.image and bgi.image.name == your_added_background_image_name:
        cam.data.background_images.remove(bgi)
        cam.data.background_images.update()
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will try the second method. I'll let you know as soon as I'm back on a computer!

Comment: Yup, second one is the one! Thanks!